# Warning: sqlsrv_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in D:\xampp5.6\htdocs\sysriomed\banco-material.php on line 27

Tags: php, sql-server

Estou fazendo um formulário para edição de materiais (produtos).
Estou visualizando a lista de materiais e eu criei no meu formulário um botão que passa o meu `IdItem`.
Estou com erro:

> Warning: sqlsrv_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource,
>   boolean given in D:\xampp5.6\htdocs\sysriomed\banco-material.php on
>   line 27

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
function buscaMaterial($conn, $IdItem){
    $query = "select m.id as IdMat, I.id as IdItem, M.nome, M.tipo, I.nSerie ,I.valorUnitario from medx.dbo.material as M, medx.dbo.itemMaterial as I on M.id=I.idMaterial where IdItem = {$IdItem}";
    $resultado = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query);
    return sqlsrv_fetch_array($resultado, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

Estou trabalhando com SQL Server 2014 e PHP 5.6.

- `banco-material.php` é a onde estão as minhas funções relacionadas aos materiais.
- `material-altera-formulario` é o formulário de edição de dados.
- `lista-material.php` é a minha lista de material.

Comment: Parece que a sua consulta falhou.

Comment: Mas no banco de dados funciona

Comment: Coloca ai o ´codigo da consulta.

Comment: Eu editei colocando o código.
Eu já tinha postado todo o conteudo no git.
sqlsrv_fetch_array retornar vários ou um resultado?

Comment: Deixe assim: `$resultado = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query) or die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors()));` Retorna apenas um elemento.

Comment: Retornou isso:

Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 42000 [SQLSTATE] => 42000 [1] => 156 [code] => 156 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Sintaxe incorreta pr�xima � palavra-chave 'on'. [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Sintaxe incorreta pr�xima � palavra-chave 'on'. ) )

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47471/discussion-between-fabricio-wm-and-rray).

Comment: Tem erro de sintaxe :P parece que faltou o `INNER JOIN` antes do `ON`

Comment: Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 42S22 [SQLSTATE] => 42S22 [1] => 207 [code] => 207 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Nome de coluna 'IdItem' inv�lido. [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Nome de coluna 'IdItem' inv�lido. ) ) 1

Comment: Eu coloquei e está dando que o nome da coluna é invalido

Comment: vc não pode usar o alias no where ou join, deve usar o nome original da coluna, no caso `I.id`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Warning: sqlsrv_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in

Isso diz que existe algum tipo de erro na sua consulta seja de sintaxe ou de violção de restrição por exemplo. Para ter certeza do que aconteceu use a função [sqlsrv_errors()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-errors.php) ela vai retornar um array com as informações do erro.

Como teste pode deixar o código dessa forma:

```
$resultado = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query) or die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors()));
```

Nesse caso o problema foi a falta do `JOIN` antes clásula `ON` e não utilizar o nome original da coluna no `WHERE`

Código original:

```
SELECT m.id as IdMat, I.id as IdItem, M.nome, M.tipo, I.nSerie ,I.valorUnitario
FROM medx.dbo.material as M, medx.dbo.itemMaterial as I on M.id=I.idMaterial
WHERE IdItem = {$IdItem}
```

Código corrigido:

```
SELECT m.id as IdMat, I.id as IdItem, M.nome, M.tipo, I.nSerie ,I.valorUnitario
FROM medx.dbo.material as M INNER JOIN medx.dbo.itemMaterial as I  on M.id = I.idMaterial
WHERE I.id = {$IdItem}
```

Comment: Mas isso só identifica. Não resolve o erro. No SQL funciona

Comment: @fabricio_wm atualizei a resposta.